# Why is "think" used, not "thinks"?

Tags: grammar

There is "Mary Reilly" in the movies starring Julia Roberts. Its preface says ───

"We are somewhere in England in the 19th century. A Pretty housemaid works in a nice house, which is Dr. Jekyll's house. Mary Reilly **think** she found her best job, because she is poor and the doctor is well-known and rich. The film tells the 'Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde' story as a woman sees the two men, one of them is good and the other is evil. And she loves them ..."

The third sentence starts with "Mary Reilly **think**".
I saw the preface in a lot of web pages and in all of them it says "Mary Reilly **think**", not "Mary Reilly **thinks**".
Why is "**think**" used here, not "**thinks**"?
She thinks she found her best job, but actually it isn't her best job.
So is "(should) **think**" used?
Would you please tell me why?

Comment: Where did you find it? Did you hear it? It could be a typo. I watched the trailer, it uses *she suspects, she protects, she shares, she feels*

Comment: It's a mistake. Could be a typing error. You have seen it lots of times because people copy text and use it on web sites and blogs without reading it.

Comment: "Should think" is not correct as "should" suggests it is an instruction, i.e. telling her what to think. I would suggest "might think". However, I agree with the previous comments saying it might be a typo and that "thinks" is correct.

Comment: helps if you share a link from an official site.

Comment: It's garbage! Why are you asking about what is obviously nonsense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**He/she is correct**

---

> Mary Reilly - isäntänä tri Jekyll (1996) - IMDb
> imdb.com›title/tt0117002/

> Mary Reilly (Julia Roberts) **think** she found her best job, because she is poor and the doctor is well-known and rich. This movie tells the "Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde" story as a woman sees the two men, one of them is good and the other is evil.

*However it must be a typo and should be **"thinks"***

Answer (score 0):

Brad, I deeply appreciate your answering my question, in spite of a question as a man named BillJ said, "It's garbage."

It is wrong as I firstly thought, isn't it? **"Think" *is* used** in the preface of *Mary Reilly* in **Scripts.com** as well as in **IMDb.com** that you showed me. That confused me. **When I googled "Mary Reilly *think* she found", I got 25 results**, but **in "Mary Reilly *thinks* she found" no results appeared**. I felt wrong and asked here.

I never expected that native English speakers would be wrong and there would be some mistakes in the preface of the movie starring Julia Roberts.

It is the same as Homer sometimes nods, isn't it? Thank you all.

Comment: Yes you are correct. As for my help; No problem, it is what I am here for.

Answer (score 0):

| SENTENCE | ANALYSIS |
| --- | --- |
| Mary Reilly **think** she found her best job | WRONG |
| Mary Reilly think**s** that she found her best job | CORRECT |

Even native speakers of English make mistakes sometimes.

You found someone's mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is well-known in Japan that Mr. George W. Bush use have / is instead of has / are. By the way, you put "that" after "thinks". Are there any different between "Mary thinks she..." and "Mary thinks that she..."?

Comment: @kerochan "Mary thinks **that** she found her dream job" is equivalent to "Mary thinks she found her dream job." Most of the rules of the English language are special cases of a general principle: delete as many words as you can while still being easy to understand. For example, words such as "**he**" and "**she**" were invented so that English-speakers would not have to repeat people's names. In some sense, we are allowed to delete a persons name after the first time we use it. "Mathew Phillips" becomes "he." In other cases, native speakers of English will omit the word "*that*" when possible